# Apollo Angular GraphQL Code Generation. Generate Queries and Mutations from single schema.graphqls file

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, graphql-codegen, apollo-angular

I'm currently trying to get the Apollo Angular Code Generation (see: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/guides/angular) to create types, queries and mutations from a single schema.graphqls file. I'm using the same schema file as in the guide

```js
type Author {
  id: Int!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  posts(findTitle: String): [Post]
}
 
type Post {
  id: Int!
  title: String!
  author: Author
}
 
type Query {
  posts: [Post]
}
```

Again, as in the guide I'm adding the necessary dependencies to my project

```bash
npm install graphql
npm install -D typescript
npm install -D @graphql-codegen/cli
npm install -D @graphql-codegen/typescript
npm install -D @graphql-codegen/typescript-operations
npm install -D @graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular
```

and I'm using the following `codegen.ts` file:

```js
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  schema: './schema.graphqls',
  generates: {
    './src/app/graphql/generated.ts': {
      plugins: [
        'typescript',
        'typescript-operations',
        'typescript-apollo-angular',
      ],
    },
  },
};
export default config;
```

After running the command `npm run generate`, I get a success notification and the specified file `./src/app/graphql/generated.ts` is generated. However in this file I only get the type definitions. The GQL files, such as `PostsGQL` as used in the final example in the Apollo Angular Code Generation guide are missing. Is there something I'm missing? Why aren't the GQL files also generated? The query appears in the schema.graphqls file, but is not in the final `generated.ts` file. Do we need to specify mutations and queries separately? If so, why?

I've created a Stackblitz with my example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-mvtcqm. In the directory codegen-example is my example Angular project with the Apollo GraphQL Code Generation and the GraphQL schema file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 sides to GraphQL:

1. Schema: The definition of your GraphQL **server** interface.
2. Operation: The definition of your GraphQL **client** query or mutation request.

You have the schema defined, but **no operations**. Say you want `PostsGQL` generated:

1. Define your operation in a .graphql file. In this case, let's do:

   ```
   # file: ./src/app/graphql/operations.graphql

   query Posts {
     posts {
       id,
       title,
       author {
         id
         firstName
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Set the documents property in your codegen config:

   ```
   // file: ./codegen.ts

   import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

   const config: CodegenConfig = {
     schema: './schema.graphqls',
     generates: {
       './src/app/graphql/generated.ts': {
         documents: './src/app/graphql/operations.graphql', // <-- Bingo!!!
         plugins: [
           'typescript',
           'typescript-operations',
           'typescript-apollo-angular',
         ],
       },
     },
   };
   export default config;
   ```
3. Run `npm run generate` and check our generated .ts file:

   ```
   // file: ./src/app/graphql/generated.ts

   // ...

   @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class PostsGQL extends Apollo.Query<PostsQuery, PostsQueryVariables> {
     document = PostsDocument;

     constructor(apollo: Apollo.Apollo) {
       super(apollo);
     }
   }
   ```

See forked example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-k4pecg

Comment: Thank you, this really helped to clear it up for me!

Comment: thanks but another related question, I want to generate all the mutations and queries that the schema defines, is there a way to do that without having to write the queries/mutations on my own?